# I keep getting syntax errors with my new vBulletin Install

Tags: vbulletin

Here is one of many errors I keep getting.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Database' (T_STRING) in /home2/craven/public_html/forums/core/includes/config.php on line 39

Comment: //    ****** DATABASE NAME ******
    //    This is the name of the database where your vBulletin will be located.
    //    This must be created by your webhost.
    $config['Database']['dbname'] = ‘forumsdb’;

Comment: //    ****** TABLE PREFIX ******
    //    Prefix that your vBulletin tables have in the database.
    $config['Database']['tableprefix'] = '';

    //    ****** TECHNICAL EMAIL ADDRESS ******
    //    If any database errors occur, they will be emailed to the address specified here.
    //    Leave this blank to not send any emails when there is a database error.
    $config['Database']['technicalemail'] = 'dbmaster@example.com';

Comment: //    ****** MASTER DATABASE USERNAME & PASSWORD ******
    //    This is the username and password you use to access MySQL.
    //    These must be obtained through your webhost.
    $config['MasterServer']['username'] = 'username’;
    $config['MasterServer']['password'] = ‘Password’;

Comment: To provide more information, please [edit] your question instead of writing them in comments. You can do so by clicking the [edit] link under your question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, you use the correct singlequotes in the config file.

These are correct: 'string', "string"
These are wrong: ´string´, `string`

You could try to replace all singlequotes with the correct double-quotes, just in case there is something funky going on with encoding in your file.

Also, make sure there are no spaces or newlines between the $config[...] definitions which might break the syntax parser.

Maybe check if the config.php file has the correct encoding, UTF-8 or any latin encodings if you're using european special characters for example. You can use a text editor like Notepad++ to check/modify the file encoding and re-upload the updated file afterwards.

If it still fails, you need to provide information about your webserver system, like the PHP version.